# protobuf with Go not able to compile to the desired folder with paths=source_relative

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I want to generate .pb.go files to the `./pb` folder. I have my .proto files under `./proto` folder. I ran this command in my root folder:

`protoc --go_out=./pb/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative ./proto/*.proto`

However, my .go files always end up under `./pb/proto` instead of `./pb` folder, like this:

```
.
|____pb
| |____proto
| | |____my_message_one.pb.go
| | |____my_message_two.pb.go
| | |____my_message_three.pb.go
```

The name of my module in `go.mod` is `module grpc_tutorial` and here's an example my .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package="./grpc_tutorial/pb"; 

message Screen {
  string some_message = 1;
  string some_message_two = 2;
  bool some_bool = 3;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my command or proto file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `--go_opt=paths=source_relative`.

If you want the generated files end up in `./pb`, then the option `--go_out=./pb/` already specifies the correct output.

By adding `source_relative`, the output mirrors the disposition of the files in the source folder ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated)):

> If the `paths=source_relative` flag is specified, the output file is placed in the **same relative directory as the input file**. For example, an input file protos/buzz.proto results in an output file at protos/buzz.pb.go.

Since your *source files* are located inside the `./proto` folder, with `source_relative` the *output files* also end up inside a `./proto` folder.

That entire output in turn ends up right where the `--go_out` flag specified, i.e. under `./pb`. This is why finally the path of a generated file looks like `./pb/proto/my_message_one.pb.go`, as you showed.

By removing the `source_relative` option, the output instead is not relativized to the source folder and goes directly into `./pb`.

The command you want in this case is just:

```
protoc --go_out=./pb/ ./proto/*.proto
```

Comment: Thanks. However, using your command, my files is now under `./pb/grpc_tutorial/pb`. Do you know where else might went wrong?

Comment: @Jyhonn because that's how you specified the Go package option. Change it to `go_package=".;pb"` for example